# Mysql query returning null records after upgrading version

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have upgraded my Mysql version from Mysql5.0 to Mysql5.5,

This is query returning `null` but same query was returning value before upgrade.

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('2010-04', '%Y-%m'), INTERVAL 2 YEAR),'%Y-%m')
```

Should return `2012-04`

My date values are of `varchar` type I want to add interval of 2 years.

Is there any other way to achieve this OR Please tell me how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql version > 5.0 `str_to_date()` sometimes would return `NULL` if the `%D` format specifier is not the last specifier in the format string input.

You need to apply some trick (specify `%D` here ).

Try below:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('2010-04-01', '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR),'%Y-%m')
```